# Emacs Shell mode: how to make TAB character pass through?

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to make TAB pass through to the shell in Emacs "Shell-mode"? I'm starting interactive console inside Shell inside Emacs and it normally prints list of candidates in response to TAB

I tried  M-x local-set-key RET C-z self-insert-command, but that just inserts TAB in the *Shell* buffer

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

In general, <kbd>C-q</kbd> lets you "quote" the following character in Emacs (not just shell mode), bypassing whatever function might be bound to it.

Comment: That has the same effect as "M-x local-set-key RET C-z self-insert-command" -- it inserts TAB into Buffer instead of passing it through to the shell

Comment: @Yuroslav:  Well, I actually tested it.  M-x shell, cat RET, C-q TAB xxx RET.  Output sure makes it look like the tab got read by the "cat" command...

Comment: hm...I'm trying to use shell's TAB auto-completion, and it doesn't seem to do it. M-x term does it, but it sends *ALL* Emacs keystrokes to the shell, whereas I only want TAB to be passed through

Answer (score 1):

Shell mode helps you to build commands in emacs and send them to some process when you press enter. Very helpful in older shells like the Bourne shell and in other interactive commands that don't allow line editing.

On the other hand, all the keypresses are being handled by emacs, so the command you're running only sees whole lines at a time. If you want to have the tab sent immediately, rather than when you press enter, I don't think shell-mode will do it.

Have you tried <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ansi-term` ?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you *want* tab-completion, but you're not getting it?

What does <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> tell you when you're in shell mode?

By default it should be bound to `comint-dynamic-complete` which ought to provide tab-completion, but something may be clobbering that binding.

You could also run `emacs -Q` to see what happens without any custom or site config files loaded.